# Fetch TimeStamp in NanoSeconds from ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a column with datatype as TIMESTAMP(9) in Oracle, which stores the datetime upto nanoseconds. E.g.: `29-JUL-15 07.30.40.887665432 PM`

While retrieving the same column through JDBC via Resultset : `rs.getTimestamp(BALANCE_TS)`

**I get the following error :**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

How can I fetch timestamp in nanoseconds from Oracle via JDBC.

Comment: Just checking - is your DB query getting the native timestamp data type, or converting it to a string? It might be useful to include the table DDL and the query in your question. The Oracle, Java and driver versions might be relevant too.

Comment: Given the error, it sounds like you are actually retrieving a string value instead of a `TIMESTAMP(9)`. Are you sure it is a `TIMESTAMP`, and that you didn't do cast or format to string? Please post a [mcve] including table definition and code for retrieval and post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Alex,Mark. For my POC i altered the  column datatype to VARCHAR long back and forgot to convert it back to TIMESTAMP(9). After your clue i just realized it. Thanks again. Cheers!